# In RoR, how do I get the params set in a Net::Http::Post request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, parameters, net-http

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  How do I get the params that were set in a Net::HTTP::Post request?  I have tried this in my Rails console

```
2.3.0 :001 > url = "https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Post.html"
 => "https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Post.html" 
2.3.0 :002 > uri = URI(url)
 => #<URI::HTTPS https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Post.html> 
2.3.0 :003 > params = {"submitbutton" => "View"}
 => {"submitbutton"=>"View"} 
2.3.0 :004 > req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
 => #<Net::HTTP::Post POST> 
2.3.0 :005 > req.set_form_data(params)
 => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
2.3.0 :008 > req.uri.params
NoMethodError: undefined method `params' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x007fe2aefba980>
Did you mean?  parser
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.3.0
```

I have also tried calling “req.params” and get the same “Undefined method error.”

Comment: Why do you want to read the params from the request object? You just set them to be the `params` hash

Comment: Why is this related to Rails?

Comment: `req.body` seems to return the form data.

Comment: Yup, req.body is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'submitbutton' => 'View')
puts res.body
```

reference:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html